# Particle Swarm Optimization - Updating Particle Position

Tags: c

I am implementing PSO in localization of particles. I have particles in random positions. I need to optimize those particles. I can't understand objective function in PSO and how to find location by these eqns.

```
Vid (k) =wVid (k − 1) + c1r1id (k)(Xpbestid − Xid ) + c2r2id (k)(Xgbestd − Xid ) 
Xid (k) =Xid (k − 1) + Vid (k)
```

Because these functions have given particle position as a single value where as I have a co-ordinate (x,y)

Comment: Where did you get this code from? It's too little information. How are `Vid` and `Xid` defined for example?

Comment: Those may well be vector equations, I think, ie Xid = {x1,x2,x3,...,xn}.

Comment: The full algorithm can be found here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_swarm_optimization

Answer (score 0):

First, you're not asking a question anywhere - what do you want to know, really?

I can make an educated guess, but if that's wrong, I've wasted my time...

Provided that what you show us is correct, then, as you say, the functions use single values as positions. That means that the single values are actually vectors, so that k={kx, ky, kz} in 3 dimensions and k={k1, k2, ..., kn} in n dimensions. The '1' is the unity vector with all dimensions equal to 1.

To **understand** the functions you need to read up on linear algebra and vector analysis.